# how does flask-login identify different users that have logged in by a single session?

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask-login, multi-user

I have know that we created a  session object with unique sessionID to response to client when a user first logged, and then when user request others' they will request with a cookie with that ID, so server can find the session object by that ID, which will denote the user have logged!

But this is one user situation, I find most blogs doesn't say if there are many users to manage, if we need to create many sessions in memory to every user. I think so!

But when I lookup flask-login source code, I can't find a session collections to maintain session for every user?

```
def login_user(user, remember=False, force=False, fresh=True):
    '''
    Logs a user in. You should pass the actual user object to this. If the
    user's `is_active` property is ``False``, they will not be logged in
    unless `force` is ``True``.

    This will return ``True`` if the log in attempt succeeds, and ``False`` if
    it fails (i.e. because the user is inactive).

    :param user: The user object to log in.
    :type user: object
    :param remember: Whether to remember the user after their session expires.
        Defaults to ``False``.
    :type remember: bool
    :param force: If the user is inactive, setting this to ``True`` will log
        them in regardless. Defaults to ``False``.
    :type force: bool
    :param fresh: setting this to ``False`` will log in the user with a session
        marked as not "fresh". Defaults to ``True``.
    :type fresh: bool
    '''
    if not force and not user.is_active:
        return False

    user_id = getattr(user, current_app.login_manager.id_attribute)()
    session['user_id'] = user_id
    session['_fresh'] = fresh
    session['_id'] = _create_identifier()

    if remember:
        session['remember'] = 'set'

    _request_ctx_stack.top.user = user
    user_logged_in.send(current_app._get_current_object(), user=_get_user())
    return True
```

There is one session to keep the user, but what if another user come?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
    flask.globals
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    Defines all the global objects that are proxies to the current
    active context.

    :copyright: (c) 2011 by Armin Ronacher.
    :license: BSD, see LICENSE for more details.
"""

from functools import partial
from werkzeug.local import LocalStack, LocalProxy


def _lookup_req_object(name):
    top = _request_ctx_stack.top
    if top is None:
        raise RuntimeError('working outside of request context')
    return getattr(top, name)


def _lookup_app_object(name):
    top = _app_ctx_stack.top
    if top is None:
        raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
    return getattr(top, name)


def _find_app():
    top = _app_ctx_stack.top
    if top is None:
        raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
    return top.app


# context locals
_request_ctx_stack = LocalStack()
_app_ctx_stack = LocalStack()
current_app = LocalProxy(_find_app)
request = LocalProxy(partial(_lookup_req_object, 'request'))
session = LocalProxy(partial(_lookup_req_object, 'session'))
g = LocalProxy(partial(_lookup_app_object, 'g'))
```

I find session is an global variable, and is an localstack(), but I still don't konw how does it works?

```
class Local(object):
    __slots__ = ('__storage__', '__ident_func__')

    def __init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, '__storage__', {})
        object.__setattr__(self, '__ident_func__', get_ident)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__storage__.items())

    def __call__(self, proxy):
        """Create a proxy for a name."""
        return LocalProxy(self, proxy)

    def __release_local__(self):
        self.__storage__.pop(self.__ident_func__(), None)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self.__storage__[self.__ident_func__()][name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        ident = self.__ident_func__()
        storage = self.__storage__
        try:
            storage[ident][name] = value
        except KeyError:
            storage[ident] = {name: value}

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        try:
            del self.__storage__[self.__ident_func__()][name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name)
```

Many people say it will use another thread id to identify, `storage[ident][name] = value` , but i disable threading, it works well for multi-users?
I just find it use current_user variable to identify current user, but current_user is so magic! It doesn't maintain user session collection but just one current_user to solve the problem! I don't know how it works?

```
def login_required(func):
    '''
    If you decorate a view with this, it will ensure that the current user is
    logged in and authenticated before calling the actual view. (If they are
    not, it calls the :attr:`LoginManager.unauthorized` callback.) For
    example::

        @app.route('/post')
        @login_required
        def post():
            pass

    If there are only certain times you need to require that your user is
    logged in, you can do so with::

        if not current_user.is_authenticated:
            return current_app.login_manager.unauthorized()

    ...which is essentially the code that this function adds to your views.

    It can be convenient to globally turn off authentication when unit testing.
    To enable this, if the application configuration variable `LOGIN_DISABLED`
    is set to `True`, this decorator will be ignored.

    .. Note ::

        Per `W3 guidelines for CORS preflight requests
        <http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0>`_,
        HTTP ``OPTIONS`` requests are exempt from login checks.

    :param func: The view function to decorate.
    :type func: function
    '''
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if request.method in EXEMPT_METHODS:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        elif current_app.login_manager._login_disabled:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        elif not current_user.is_authenticated:
            return current_app.login_manager.unauthorized()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view
```

So where is process of  comparing current user sessionID from cookie with session collection mantained by server? Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2):

I take a look at [flask-login/flask_login/login_manager.py:_load_user()](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/flask_login/login_manager.py)

I guess you are talking about SESSION_PROTECTION. In this case the way user will be reloaded depends on basic or strong auth modes. If you have no session protection, flask try to load the user from request, header or cookies if you have handlers for this.

```
class LoginManager(object):
...

def _load_user(self):
    '''Loads user from session or remember_me cookie as applicable'''
    user_accessed.send(current_app._get_current_object())

    # first check SESSION_PROTECTION
    config = current_app.config
    if config.get('SESSION_PROTECTION', self.session_protection):
        deleted = self._session_protection()
        if deleted:
            return self.reload_user()

    # If a remember cookie is set, and the session is not, move the
    # cookie user ID to the session.
    #
    # However, the session may have been set if the user has been
    # logged out on this request, 'remember' would be set to clear,
    # so we should check for that and not restore the session.
    is_missing_user_id = 'user_id' not in session
    if is_missing_user_id:
        cookie_name = config.get('REMEMBER_COOKIE_NAME', COOKIE_NAME)
        header_name = config.get('AUTH_HEADER_NAME', AUTH_HEADER_NAME)
        has_cookie = (cookie_name in request.cookies and
                      session.get('remember') != 'clear')
        if has_cookie:
            return self._load_from_cookie(request.cookies[cookie_name])
        elif self.request_callback:
            return self._load_from_request(request)
        elif header_name in request.headers:
            return self._load_from_header(request.headers[header_name])

    return self.reload_user()

def _load_from_request(self, request):
    user = None
    if self.request_callback:
        user = self.request_callback(request)
    if user is not None:
        self.reload_user(user=user)
        app = current_app._get_current_object()
        user_loaded_from_request.send(app, user=_get_user())
    else:
        self.reload_user()
```

Flask passes request to your callback if it presented. Flask-login has good [example(Custom Login using Request Loader)](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) how you can load user from request.

```
@login_manager.request_loader
def load_user_from_request(request):

# first, try to login using the api_key url arg
api_key = request.args.get('api_key')
if api_key:
    user = User.query.filter_by(api_key=api_key).first()
    if user:
        return user

# next, try to login using Basic Auth
api_key = request.headers.get('Authorization')
if api_key:
    api_key = api_key.replace('Basic ', '', 1)
    try:
        api_key = base64.b64decode(api_key)
    except TypeError:
        pass
    user = User.query.filter_by(api_key=api_key).first()
    if user:
        return user

# finally, return None if both methods did not login the user
return None
```

The api_key can be assigned when a client will be authorized through the backend for different logins from one physical machine.

Comment: From a request or cookie? But this comes from a client, i think the server remember a user by recording it in memory with user session collections, So if an user has logged, there will be one session in collections contains the user, then the user logged status can be maintained. You say load user from a request, I don't understand?

Comment: @kitian I expanded my answer